# AWS Lightsail Mean Stack Setup

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, mean-stack, amazon-lightsail

I'm playing around with AWS Lightsail and having a hard time understanding how to actually get it setup. I've created a Bitnami MEAN instance and it's running correctly.

Locally, I'm running Angular 6 via CLI and a NODE API backend. Two different ports, 4200 and 3000 respectively.

When I log into the lightsail instance I see the HTDOCS folder but this is Apache and not node. I've run a 'build' of my angular project so I have the files to load to a webserver, but I'd like to run my API next to the instance so I can call the API for server stuff

Trying to figure out how to go about this. I've watched an AWS video on it but it appears it's tightly coupled to the authors app. I was lookign for more general instructions.

Any help on structure and location of files and where I should locate them?

Comment: Did you figure this out?  @Mike Varela

Answer (score 0):

Depends what image you use. Lightsail is just a type of instance, which is kind of isolated from aws ecosystem(I would go for a ec2 t2 instance).

When you start an instance you select an image with an operating system. It doesn't mean it comes with the nodejs. You have to install it after you start the image(or to look for an image which has nodejs preinstalled).

If it has node installed, usually, in linux it's an obsolete version. Better to install nvm and then to select the desired node version.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I agree that a full EC2 instance might be better but the cost savings here is nice. I guess my main question is how to run two services on lighsail at once. One for webserver and one for client. At home I'm running localhost for two ports but can't figure our how to do it there

Answer (score 0):

There is an Apache server pre-installed and running by default. You can turn that off as follows:

`sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh stop apache`

`sudo mv /opt/bitnami/apache2/scripts/ctl.sh /opt/bitnami/apache2/scripts/ctl.sh.disabled`

This will prevent apache from running in the future and free up port 80 if you want to use it for your front end.

There shouldn't be any other magic you need to do (except making sure you open port 3000 in the firewall for your web front end if you want to access it remotely). The API and front end should easily live together on your lightsail instance the same way they do on your localhost.

Comment: Thanks Mike. That’s helpful. So basically turn off Apache. Then load two folders. One for front end and one for back end. Front end is 80. Back is 8080. Then run node for both to start those servers?